# How can I find the position in the page of an element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position

I'm aware of the position method, but that retrieves the position relative to the offset parent. Do I just throw in a loop to transverse up the document nodes?

I guess that I'm surprised that it isn't part of the core, and I'm wondering if it's tucked away somewhere that I don't know about.

Comment: could you please clarify what you mean by position? Do you mean index in the DOM or css positions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
jQuery(elem).offset();
```

See http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset for a summary

Comment: thanks. i was pretty sure it was in there. i kept looking under the transversing section.

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery you can use:

```
document.getElementById('elemId').clientTop
document.getElementById('elemId').clientLeft
```

or

```
document.getElementById('elemId').offsetTop
document.getElementById('elemId').offsetLeft
```

Comment: clientLeft and clientTop are IE only.

Other browsers use offsetLeft and offsetTop, but jQuery nicely wraps up all the inconsistencies for you

Comment: Didn't know about that, because i just tried to retrieve this with Firebug and works. 
I edit my post so other people will know about it... Thanks for the tip